# Expo v27/v28 Android App with websocket is crashing

Tags: android, websocket, expo

**Environment:** Android 6 Marshmallow and iOS(all versions)

**Error:** Android app with WebSockets is crashing with error:

`WebSocketModule.close got 1 arguments, expected 3.`

The error happens when I close the WebSocket connection just on Android, for instance:

```
this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
this.ws.onopen = () => {
    const command = { command: 'JOIN', room: roonHash };
    this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(command));
};

this.ws.onmessage = e => {
    //more code here
};


// Finally:
this.ws.close();
```

**iOS:**
On iOS it works fine.

I'm using Expo v27 but I got the same error on v28.
Is there any workaround fixing that until the Expo/React Native team fixes it forever?

Comment: They've closed both issues on GitHub: [expo v27 Android app with websocket is crashing](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1698), [expo v28 Android app with websocket is crashing](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1866).

Comment: Are you talking about that? : 
@seiichi Thank you for verifying the fix. We have released https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.2.tar.gz which has the commit from 0.55.3 that fixes this issue.

Comment: I guess so. I meant in general when you say "until the Expo/React Native team fixes it forever" they think you don't have to wait, they've already done it.

Comment: And why it had appeared again on v28? Very strange the error be solver and appear again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Expo v27**

> Update your React Native/Expo v27.0.0 to v27.0.2 on your `package.json`

**Expo v28**

> Update your React Native/Expo v28.0.0 to v28.0.1 on your `package.json`

Procedures:

1) Go to your `package.json` file and change the version of your expo, for example:

```
From:

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",

To:

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.2.tar.gz",
```

2) Delete your node_modules:

`$ rm -rf node_modules`

3) Install it again:

`$ yarn install`